# IFormFile content is empty when sent from client

Tags: python, .net, rest, iformfile

I have a python client that is sending a file to a dotnet6 backend.

```
files = {'file': open(str(file_uuid), 'rb')}
requests.post(' https://localhost:5001/Measurement', files=files, verify=False)
```

By the time this hits my controller the length is 0.
[image]

```
    [HttpPost("")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit] 
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

When I send this same file through Insomnia I don't have this issue.